# Graphics card memory showing 256mb in-game

Tags: graphics-card, upgrade, thinkpad

Im using Lenovo ThinkPad T440p. It has intel i7 4600 and Intel HD 4600 inbuilt gfx card.

CPU-Z shows 2GB graphicsa ram while in-game I get only 256mb available graphics.

Please guide, also can i upgrade my laptop graphics card ?

complete system info(dxdiag): http://pastebin.com/FWbFkKkS

[image: Intel HD4600]

Comment: The Lenovo range of Thinkpads is extremely customisable. The T440p has 4 base models each with several choices of CPU, RAM, GPU, etc. The fact that you've only given very minimal information is going to make it tricky to tell you why this is happening.

Comment: complete system info(dxdiag): http://pastebin.com/FWbFkKkS

Comment: Are you using XP?!

Comment: @EaterOfCode What makes you think that? From the pastebin: Operating System: Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit...

Comment: @Mixxiphoid because of the theme, looks like Win ME even

Comment: @EaterOfCode I use that theme whenever I build a Win7 machine. It's just cleaner and less intensive on the graphics system.

Answer (score 2):

Because the Intel HD4600 is integrated, it doesn't have any memory of it's own. So you're effectively sharing the RAM between the programs you are running and the graphics adapter.

Intel have a good explanation about this here http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-029090.htm

I think you'll need to approach this issue from a different angle and possibly figure out why the game you are running is only trying to grab such a small amount of memory for the graphics adapter.

Comment: Adding memory to a Thinkpad is straighforward, e.g. see http://forum.notebookreview.com/lenovo/733540-thinkpad-t440p-hmm-userguide-posted.html

Comment: The pastbin post claims his machine has 16GB of memory.
             Memory: 16384MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 16072MB RAM

Comment: @Micheal Frank My laptop has 16GB DDR3 RAM, its intel i7 4600 CPU.

Comment: Yea, I'm not sure exactly how I managed to see 2GB of RAM.